# get date out of a variable separated by comma and curly brackets

Tags: jquery, bigcommerce

I am using big commerce and in that there is a product end date and start date . I wanted to get the end date and start date from a kind of value is returning when the product page loads . The values come as

```
var eventDateData = {type:'3',compDate:'2014/04/18',compDateEnd:'',invalidMessage:'Please choose a valid product listing end date first.',errorMessage:'The product listing end date must be on or before 18th Apr 2014.'};
```

this variable is coming from big commerce . How can i take out the date `compDate` and `compDateEnd` in two separate variables ?

Comment: `var compDate = eventDateData.compDate;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign them:

```
var compDate    = eventDateData.compDate,
    compDateEnd = eventDateData.compDateEnd;
```

Comment: Its not working. Since it gets complied when the page loads . and when i alert any of the values it alerts blank

Comment: @user1001176 -- That's most likely because the call to get this data is async. The above notation is correct, but without seeing how you get the data I can't post a better answer.

Comment: Ok its working now when i put this code little away from the header where the other code is . but now when i am trying to store its value inside hidden field that is not happening ? `document.getElementById("product_compDate").value = compDate;` it says cannot set value of null . But there is a hidden field with that id

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access it using [`.` (simple dot-notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
console.log(eventDateData.compDate);
console.log(eventDateData.compDateEnd);
```